# Random but most likely 1 float

Tags: java, math, random

I want to randomize a float that so that

- There is 95% chance to be about 1
- There is 0.01% chance to be < 0.1 or > 1.9
- It never becomes 0 or 2

Is this possible by using `Random.nextFloat()` several times for example?

A visual illustration of the probability:

[image: A visual illustration of the probability]

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20327958/random-number-with-probabilities) may help

Answer (score 7):

You need to find a function *f* such that:

1. f is continuous and increasing on [0, 1]
2. f(0) > 0 and f(1) < 2
3. f(0.01) >= 0.1 and f(0.99) <= 1.9
4. f(x) is "about 1" for 0.025 <= x <= 0.975

And then just take `f(Random.nextDouble())`

For example, `Math.tan(3*(x-0.5))/14.11` fits this, so for your expression I'd use:

```
Math.tan(3*(Random.nextDouble()-0.5))/14.11
```

The probability is distributed as:

[image: Wolfram cloud session]

Comment: Note that this may not be close enough to 1 for your purposes 95% of the time (the 95% range is actually [0.5, 1.5] with this function), so you might try a different function, like `double t = Math.tan(3*Random.nextDouble()-0.5); return t*t*t/2805.0;`

Answer (score 2):

I do not code in **JAVA** but anyway, if I would want to use the internal pseudo-random generator (I usually use different approaches for this) I would do it like this:

1. **Definitions**

   Let's say we have pseudo-random generator `Random.nextFloat()` returning values in range `<0,1>` with uniform distribution.
2. **Create mapping from uniform `<0,1>` to yours `(0,2)`**

   It would be something like:

   [image: mapping]

   **THE 0.001 SHOULD BE 0.0001 !!!** I taught it was 0.1% instead 0.01% while drawing ...

   Let's call it `f(x)`. It can be a table (piecewise interpolation), or construct some polynomial that will match the properties you need (**BEZIER**,Interpolation polynomials,...)

   As you can see the `x` axis is the probability and the `y` axis is the pseudo-random value (in your range). As built-in pseudo-random generators are uniform, they will generate uniformly distributed numbers between `<0,1>` which can be directly used as `x`.

   To avoid the `0.0` and `2.0` either throw them away or use interval `<0.0+ulp,2.0-ulp>` where [ulp is unit in last place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place)

   The graph is drawn in Paint and consists of 2x cubic **BEZIER** (4 control points per cubic) and a single Line.
3. **Now just convert the ranges**

   So your pseudo-random value will be:

   ```
   value=f(Random.nextFloat());
   ```

**[Notes]**

This would be better with fixed point format numbers otherwise you need to make the curvatures insanely high order to make any effect or use **very huge** amount of data to match desired probability output.